# Formatting Latex Table

Tags: tables

I have created a table in latex. However, the table is covering the entire page, and I cannot see some of the columns. It would be great if someone can help me format the table. Thanks!

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{graphics,lscape} \usepackage{amsmath}   
\usepackage{rotating,multirow,varwidth,setspace}
\usepackage{latexsym,amssymb,epsfig}
\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow} 
\usepackage[tablename=TABLE,labelsep=newline,aboveskip=0pt,bf]{caption}
\usepackage{clipboard,booktabs,ltablex,threeparttablex}
\usepackage{afterpage,sectsty,textcase,longtable,fancyvrb} 
\usepackage{sepfootnotes,changepage,bibentry}
\usepackage{siunitx,geometry,pdfpages} 
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref} 
\usepackage[titletoc,toc,title]{appendix}
\crefname{appsec}{Appendix}{Appendices}

\protected\def\stars#1{$^{#1}$} \newcolumntype{k}{>{\hsize=.1\hsize}S}

%Set Counter  \setcounter{footnote}{2}

%Defining text size to control for spacing in tabularx environment  \newcolumntype{b}[1]{>{\centering}>X} \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} \newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}>{\hsize=.2\textwidth}>X} %\newcolumntype{s}{>{\centering}>{\hsize=.25\hsize}>X} \newcolumntype{j}{>{\centering}>{\hsize=.2\textwidth}>X}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}} \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}} \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

%Redefining multicolumn environment to take care of @{} \newcommand{\gmc}[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{@{}#2@{}}} %\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\\\hspace*{\fill}$\blacksquare$}

\newcommand*{\tabnospace}{\item \noindent \hspace{-0.05in}}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\geometry{margin=0.75in} \usepackage[none]{hyphenat} \doublespacing

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}

\begin{ThreePartTable}      \begin{TableNotes}[flushleft]       \small      \tabnospace This table presents the difference-in-difference results for the impact of board size on financing activities in the wake of deteriorating macroeconomic condition. The dependent variables are long term debt and cash scaled by sales. The estimates of different controls are illustrated for different periods of Survey of Professional Forecasts (SPF). Anxious index represents the probability that real GDP will decline in the quarter in which the survey is taken. CG represents a measure of corporate governance, in this case, board size, calculated one-year prior to the quarter of survey. AFTER is an indicator variable equal to one for four fiscal quarters after the month of survey, and equals to 0 for four quarters prior to the month of survey. BTM represents book-to-market ratio, AT represents total assets, and REV represents total revenue for the quarter. All regressions include firm, and fiscal quarter fixed effects. The t-statistics, presented in parentheses below the coefficients, are corrected for heteroskedasticity and cross-sectional and time-series correlations using a two-way cluster at the firm and year-quarter levels. ***, **, and * denote significance at 1\%, 5\%, and 10\% levels for two-tailed tests respectively.   \end{TableNotes}        \singlespacing  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}p{0.8in}p{0.5in}p{0.5in}p{0.5in}p{0.5in}p{0.5in}p{0.5in}p{0.5in}p{0.5in}p{0.5in}p{0.5in}p{0.5in}@{}}
                \caption{\textit{Board Size and Financing Activities as Macroeconomic Conditions Deteriorate}}\\\toprule\toprule        SPF Month'Year & Feb'07 & May'07 & Aug'07 & Nov'07 & Feb'08 & May'08 & Aug'08 & Nov'08 & Feb'09 & May'09 \\\hline       Anxious Index & 8.28 &
11.75 & 12.44 & 18.89 & 47.31 & 49.07 & 34.09 & 90.14 & 94.41 & 78.91  \\\hline \\      \endfirsthead
                \caption{\textit{Board Size and Financing Activities as Macroeconomic Conditions Deteriorate - Continued}}\\\toprule\toprule        SPF Month'Year & Feb'07 & May'07 & Aug'07 & Nov'07 & Feb'08 & May'08 & Aug'08 & Nov'08 & Feb'09 & May'09 \\\hline       Anxious Index & 8.28 &
11.75 & 12.44 & 18.89 & 47.31 & 49.07 & 34.09 & 90.14 & 94.41 & 78.91  \\\hline \\      \endhead

        \bottomrule\gmc{12}{r}{\small\textit{(Continued)}}\endfoot      \bottomrule\insertTableNotes\endlastfoot
                \gmc{12}{l}{Dependent Variable: Long Term Debt/Sale} \\\hline
     AFTER &     $0.047^{}$ &     $0.038^{}$ &     $0.036^{}$ &     $0.047^{}$ &  $0.073^{**}$ &  $0.118^{***}$ &  $0.155^{***}$ &  $0.158^{***}$ &   $0.064^{**}$ &  $-0.071^{**}$ & $-0.183^{***}$ \\
           &        (1.458) &        (1.339) &        (1.159) &        (1.347) &        (1.98) &        (3.145) &        (4.518) &        (4.827) &        (2.477) &       (-2.526) &       (-5.856) \\   AFTER:CG &   $-0.074^{*}$ &   $-0.066^{*}$ &  $-0.073^{**}$ &   $-0.058^{*}$ &   $-0.053^{}$ &    $-0.035^{}$ &     $-0.03^{}$ &    $-0.037^{}$ &    $-0.038^{}$ &    $-0.041^{}$ &    $-0.004^{}$ \\
           &        (-1.93) &       (-1.793) &       (-2.143) &       (-1.849) &      (-1.207) &       (-1.054) &       (-1.025) &       (-1.172) &        (-1.39) &       (-1.533) &       (-0.192) \\
        AT &      $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ &     $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ \\
           &        (3.445) &        (3.498) &        (3.694) &        (3.907) &       (4.266) &        (4.175) &        (4.491) &        (4.551) &        (4.495) &        (4.457) &        (4.473) \\
       BTM & $-1.098^{***}$ & $-0.917^{***}$ & $-0.768^{***}$ & $-0.647^{***}$ & $-0.47^{***}$ & $-0.359^{***}$ & $-0.369^{***}$ & $-0.376^{***}$ & $-0.353^{***}$ & $-0.357^{***}$ &  $-0.38^{***}$ \\
           &       (-3.898) &       (-3.684) &       (-3.495) &       (-3.316) &      (-2.923) &       (-2.606) &       (-2.799) &       (-2.877) &       (-2.721) &         (-2.6) &       (-2.785) \\
        CG &  $0.247^{***}$ &   $0.204^{**}$ &   $0.185^{**}$ &     $0.114^{}$ &    $0.091^{}$ &     $0.028^{}$ &     $0.007^{}$ &     $0.014^{}$ &     $0.084^{}$ &     $0.088^{}$ &     $0.068^{}$ \\
           &        (2.591) &        (2.239) &        (2.159) &        (1.383) &       (1.298) &        (0.438) &        (0.107) &        (0.212) &          (1.5) &        (1.539) &        (1.183) \\
       REV &      $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ &     $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ \\
           &       (-5.245) &       (-5.129) &       (-5.263) &       (-5.325) &      (-5.598) &       (-5.515) &       (-5.679) &       (-5.683) &       (-5.655) &       (-5.574) &       (-5.484) \\
         N &          15120 &          14648 &          14760 &          15040 &         15472 &          15104 &          15104 &          15312 &          15584 &          14680 &          14704 \\
     $R^2$ &          0.183 &          0.181 &           0.18 &          0.176 &         0.182 &          0.181 &          0.182 &          0.185 &          0.191 &          0.199 &          0.214 \\  Adj $R^2$ &          0.179 &          0.178 &          0.176 &          0.172 & 
0.179 &          0.178 &          0.179 &          0.182 &          0.188 &          0.195 &           0.21 \\\hline
                \gmc{12}{l}{Dependent Variable: Cash and Cash Equivalents/Sale} \\\hline    
     AFTER & $-0.962^{***}$ & $-0.99^{***}$ & $-0.772^{***}$ & $-0.785^{***}$ & $-0.768^{***}$ & $-0.72^{***}$ & $-0.628^{***}$ & $-0.662^{***}$ & $-0.74^{***}$ & $-0.566^{***}$ & $-0.409^{***}$ \\
          &       (-3.227) &      (-4.115) &       (-3.624) &       (-3.598) &       (-3.548) &      (-3.604) &       (-3.557) &       (-3.845) &      (-4.198) &       (-3.351) &       (-2.584) \\   AFTER:CG &     $0.148^{}$ &    $0.195^{}$ &     $0.189^{}$ &     $0.46^{*}$ &     $0.374^{}$ &  $0.496^{**}$ &     $0.388^{}$ &    $0.411^{*}$ &    $0.235^{}$ &     $0.216^{}$ &     $0.209^{}$ \\
           &        (0.338) &       (0.564) &        (0.711) &        (1.883) &        (1.343) &       (2.114) &        (1.625) &        (1.847) &       (1.253) &        (1.226) &        (1.229) \\
        AT &       $0^{**}$ &       $0^{*}$ &        $0^{*}$ &        $0^{*}$ &        $0^{*}$ &       $0^{*}$ &        $0^{*}$ &       $0^{**}$ &     $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ \\
           &       (-2.146) &      (-1.875) &       (-1.798) &       (-1.805) &       (-1.803) &      (-1.663) &       (-1.744) &       (-2.023) &      (-2.732) &       (-2.955) &       (-3.211) \\
       BTM &  $-2.588^{**}$ &  $-2.041^{*}$ &  $-1.817^{**}$ &   $-1.373^{*}$ &    $-0.946^{}$ &   $-0.835^{}$ &    $-0.713^{}$ &  $-0.823^{**}$ & $-0.893^{**}$ &  $-0.799^{**}$ & $-0.825^{***}$ \\
           &       (-1.983) &      (-1.849) &       (-2.028) &       (-1.742) &       (-1.508) &      (-1.631) &       (-1.644) &       (-2.154) &      (-2.541) &       (-2.282) &       (-2.612) \\
        CG &    $-0.069^{}$ &    $-0.21^{}$ &    $-0.311^{}$ &     $0.015^{}$ &    $-0.734^{}$ &  $-0.859^{*}$ &    $-0.619^{}$ &    $-0.592^{}$ &   $-0.027^{}$ &    $-0.041^{}$ &    $-0.058^{}$ \\
           &       (-0.105) &      (-0.309) &        (-0.52) &        (0.028) &        (-1.38) &      (-1.824) &       (-1.479) &       (-1.518) &       (-0.09) &       (-0.141) &       (-0.216) \\
       REV &         $0^{}$ &        $0^{}$ &         $0^{}$ &         $0^{}$ &         $0^{}$ &        $0^{}$ &         $0^{}$ &         $0^{}$ &        $0^{}$ &         $0^{}$ &         $0^{}$ \\
           &       (-0.305) &      (-0.397) &       (-0.389) &       (-0.417) &       (-0.507) &      (-0.873) &       (-0.933) &        (-0.96) &      (-0.743) &       (-0.608) &       (-0.447) \\
         N &          15440 &         15016 &          15128 &          15392 &          15808 &         15424 &          15448 &          15648 &         15968 &          15048 &          15072 \\
     $R^2$ &           0.11 &         0.116 &          0.111 &          0.107 &           0.11 &          0.12 &           0.12 &          0.126 &         0.131 &          0.137 &          0.144 \\  Adj $R^2$ &          0.106 &         0.112 &          0.107 &          0.103 &  
0.106 &         0.116 &          0.116 &          0.123 &         0.127 &          0.133 &           0.14 \\

\end{tabularx}   \end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As posted, your code won't compile. Something lost in the formatting, perhaps?

Comment: Off-topic: your code is far from minimal. In any case, you should prune your preamble for your original document. You are using packages you almost certainly don't need, including some long obsolete, and loading them in the wrong order etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few notes:

- the preamble is rather problematic: it includes too much which is too ancient and too disordered e.g. `hyperref` needs to be loaded *late* - `cleverref` must come later, but almost everything else should come earlier; `epsfig` is obsolete; etc.
- `tabularx` requires one or more `X` columns in some guise or other.

The table doesn't fit the page.

The first thing to ask is whether the data can be summarised more concisely or split more perspicuously. This is a content question only you (or somebody in your field) can answer. However, I think it is surely unnecessary to tell readers that `Feb'07` gives a month/year. I'm not a specialist in your area, but even I know that much ;).

If that strategy isn't sufficient, the second thing is to consider the format. Simply shrinking the table to the page size is unwise. Mismatched font sizes are ugly and distracting. Moreover, in this case, the approach will render the table unreadable.

The following solution does a few things:

- rotates the table, so that the height of the paper is available for the width of the table;
- reduces visual clutter by implementing `booktabs`'s guidelines more consistently (don't use `\hline`, don't use double rules, use rules which add sufficient space rather than empty rows etc.);
- uses `longtable` and `l` column specifiers as the `p{}`s were not really doing much and no `X` columns were used anyway;
- applies `\small` to the entire table since it is simply not ever going to fit otherwise unless the paper size is increased.

[image: fitting table]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[tablename=TABLE,labelsep=newline,aboveskip=0pt,bf]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs,threeparttablex}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{geometry}
\newcommand{\gmc}[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand*{\tabnospace}{\item \noindent \hspace{-0.05in}}
\geometry{margin=0.75in}
\doublespacing
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
  \small
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
  \begin{ThreePartTable}
    \begin{TableNotes}[flushleft]
      \small
      \tabnospace
      This table presents the difference-in-difference results for the impact of board size on financing activities in the wake of deteriorating macroeconomic condition. The dependent variables are long term debt and cash scaled by sales. The estimates of different controls are illustrated for different periods of Survey of Professional Forecasts (SPF). Anxious index represents the probability that real GDP will decline in the quarter in which the survey is taken. CG represents a measure of corporate governance, in this case, board size, calculated one-year prior to the quarter of survey. AFTER is an indicator variable equal to one for four fiscal quarters after the month of survey, and equals to 0 for four quarters prior to the month of survey. BTM represents book-to-market ratio, AT represents total assets, and REV represents total revenue for the quarter. All regressions include firm, and fiscal quarter fixed effects. The t-statistics, presented in parentheses below the coefficients, are corrected for heteroskedasticity and cross-sectional and time-series correlations using a two-way cluster at the firm and year-quarter levels. ***, **, and * denote significance at 1\%, 5\%, and 10\% levels for two-tailed tests respectively.
    \end{TableNotes}
    \singlespacing
    \begin{longtable}{*{12}{l}}
      \caption{\textit{Board Size and Financing Activities as Macroeconomic Conditions Deteriorate}}\\
      \toprule
      SPF & Feb'07 & May'07 & Aug'07 & Nov'07 & Feb'08 & May'08 & Aug'08 & Nov'08 & Feb'09 & May'09 \\
      Anxious Index & 8.28 &
      11.75 & 12.44 & 18.89 & 47.31 & 49.07 & 34.09 & 90.14 & 94.41 & 78.91  \\
      \midrule
      \endfirsthead
      \caption{\textit{Board Size and Financing Activities as Macroeconomic Conditions Deteriorate --- Continued}}\\
      \toprule
      SPF & Feb'07 & May'07 & Aug'07 & Nov'07 & Feb'08 & May'08 & Aug'08 & Nov'08 & Feb'09 & May'09 \\
      Anxious Index & 8.28 &
      11.75 & 12.44 & 18.89 & 47.31 & 49.07 & 34.09 & 90.14 & 94.41 & 78.91  \\
      \midrule
      \endhead
      \bottomrule
      \gmc{12}{r}{\small\textit{(Continued)}}
      \endfoot
      \bottomrule\insertTableNotes
      \endlastfoot
      \gmc{12}{l}{Dependent Variable: Long Term Debt/Sale} \\\midrule
      AFTER &     $0.047^{}$ &     $0.038^{}$ &     $0.036^{}$ &     $0.047^{}$ &  $0.073^{**}$ &  $0.118^{***}$ &  $0.155^{***}$ &  $0.158^{***}$ &   $0.064^{**}$ &  $-0.071^{**}$ & $-0.183^{***}$ \\
      &        (1.458) &        (1.339) &        (1.159) &        (1.347) &        (1.98) &        (3.145) &        (4.518) &        (4.827) &        (2.477) &       (-2.526) &       (-5.856) \\
      AFTER: CG &   $-0.074^{*}$ &   $-0.066^{*}$ &  $-0.073^{**}$ &   $-0.058^{*}$ &   $-0.053^{}$ &    $-0.035^{}$ &     $-0.03^{}$ &    $-0.037^{}$ &    $-0.038^{}$ &    $-0.041^{}$ &    $-0.004^{}$ \\
      &        (-1.93) &       (-1.793) &       (-2.143) &       (-1.849) &      (-1.207) &       (-1.054) &       (-1.025) &       (-1.172) &        (-1.39) &       (-1.533) &       (-0.192) \\
      AT &      $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ &     $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ \\
      &        (3.445) &        (3.498) &        (3.694) &        (3.907) &       (4.266) &        (4.175) &        (4.491) &        (4.551) &        (4.495) &        (4.457) &        (4.473) \\
      BTM & $-1.098^{***}$ & $-0.917^{***}$ & $-0.768^{***}$ & $-0.647^{***}$ & $-0.47^{***}$ & $-0.359^{***}$ & $-0.369^{***}$ & $-0.376^{***}$ & $-0.353^{***}$ & $-0.357^{***}$ &  $-0.38^{***}$ \\
      &       (-3.898) &       (-3.684) &       (-3.495) &       (-3.316) &      (-2.923) &       (-2.606) &       (-2.799) &       (-2.877) &       (-2.721) &         (-2.6) &       (-2.785) \\
      CG &  $0.247^{***}$ &   $0.204^{**}$ &   $0.185^{**}$ &     $0.114^{}$ &    $0.091^{}$ &     $0.028^{}$ &     $0.007^{}$ &     $0.014^{}$ &     $0.084^{}$ &     $0.088^{}$ &     $0.068^{}$ \\
      &        (2.591) &        (2.239) &        (2.159) &        (1.383) &       (1.298) &        (0.438) &        (0.107) &        (0.212) &          (1.5) &        (1.539) &        (1.183) \\
      REV &      $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ &     $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ \\
      &       (-5.245) &       (-5.129) &       (-5.263) &       (-5.325) &      (-5.598) &       (-5.515) &       (-5.679) &       (-5.683) &       (-5.655) &       (-5.574) &       (-5.484) \\
      N &          15120 &          14648 &          14760 &          15040 &         15472 &          15104 &          15104 &          15312 &          15584 &          14680 &          14704 \\
      $R^2$ &          0.183 &          0.181 &           0.18 &          0.176 &         0.182 &          0.181 &          0.182 &          0.185 &          0.191 &          0.199 &          0.214 \\  Adj $R^2$ &          0.179 &          0.178 &          0.176 &          0.172 &
      0.179 &          0.178 &          0.179 &          0.182 &          0.188 &          0.195 &           0.21 \\\midrule
      \gmc{12}{l}{Dependent Variable: Cash and Cash Equivalents/Sale}
      \\\midrule
      AFTER & $-0.962^{***}$ & $-0.99^{***}$ & $-0.772^{***}$ & $-0.785^{***}$ & $-0.768^{***}$ & $-0.72^{***}$ & $-0.628^{***}$ & $-0.662^{***}$ & $-0.74^{***}$ & $-0.566^{***}$ & $-0.409^{***}$ \\
      &       (-3.227) &      (-4.115) &       (-3.624) &       (-3.598) &       (-3.548) &      (-3.604) &       (-3.557) &       (-3.845) &      (-4.198) &       (-3.351) &       (-2.584) \\
      AFTER:CG &     $0.148^{}$ &    $0.195^{}$ &     $0.189^{}$ &     $0.46^{*}$ &     $0.374^{}$ &  $0.496^{**}$ &     $0.388^{}$ &    $0.411^{*}$ &    $0.235^{}$ &     $0.216^{}$ &     $0.209^{}$ \\
      &        (0.338) &       (0.564) &        (0.711) &        (1.883) &        (1.343) &       (2.114) &        (1.625) &        (1.847) &       (1.253) &        (1.226) &        (1.229) \\
      AT &       $0^{**}$ &       $0^{*}$ &        $0^{*}$ &        $0^{*}$ &        $0^{*}$ &       $0^{*}$ &        $0^{*}$ &       $0^{**}$ &     $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ &      $0^{***}$ \\
      &       (-2.146) &      (-1.875) &       (-1.798) &       (-1.805) &       (-1.803) &      (-1.663) &       (-1.744) &       (-2.023) &      (-2.732) &       (-2.955) &       (-3.211) \\
      BTM &  $-2.588^{**}$ &  $-2.041^{*}$ &  $-1.817^{**}$ &   $-1.373^{*}$ &    $-0.946^{}$ &   $-0.835^{}$ &    $-0.713^{}$ &  $-0.823^{**}$ & $-0.893^{**}$ &  $-0.799^{**}$ & $-0.825^{***}$ \\
      &       (-1.983) &      (-1.849) &       (-2.028) &       (-1.742) &       (-1.508) &      (-1.631) &       (-1.644) &       (-2.154) &      (-2.541) &       (-2.282) &       (-2.612) \\
      CG &    $-0.069^{}$ &    $-0.21^{}$ &    $-0.311^{}$ &     $0.015^{}$ &    $-0.734^{}$ &  $-0.859^{*}$ &    $-0.619^{}$ &    $-0.592^{}$ &   $-0.027^{}$ &    $-0.041^{}$ &    $-0.058^{}$ \\
      &       (-0.105) &      (-0.309) &        (-0.52) &        (0.028) &        (-1.38) &      (-1.824) &       (-1.479) &       (-1.518) &       (-0.09) &       (-0.141) &       (-0.216) \\
      REV &         $0^{}$ &        $0^{}$ &         $0^{}$ &         $0^{}$ &         $0^{}$ &        $0^{}$ &         $0^{}$ &         $0^{}$ &        $0^{}$ &         $0^{}$ &         $0^{}$ \\
      &       (-0.305) &      (-0.397) &       (-0.389) &       (-0.417) &       (-0.507) &      (-0.873) &       (-0.933) &        (-0.96) &      (-0.743) &       (-0.608) &       (-0.447) \\
      N &          15440 &         15016 &          15128 &          15392 &          15808 &         15424 &          15448 &          15648 &         15968 &          15048 &          15072 \\
      $R^2$ &           0.11 &         0.116 &          0.111 &          0.107 &           0.11 &          0.12 &           0.12 &          0.126 &         0.131 &          0.137 &          0.144 \\  Adj $R^2$ &          0.106 &         0.112 &          0.107 &          0.103 &
      0.106 &         0.116 &          0.116 &          0.123 &         0.127 &          0.133 &           0.14 \\
    \end{longtable}
  \end{ThreePartTable}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the variant of latex you use (latex, pdflatex, xelatex, etc.), the canonical way is to rotate the table, and if necessary to minimize it.

You might need `\usepackage{graphicx}` rather than `\usepackage{graphics}`

```
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
  \begin{tabularx}
  …
  \end{tabularx}}
```

Might work.

Comment: 'Canonical'? Certainly not in the sense of 'recommended' ;).

Comment: In this case, this suggestion will fail badly as you cannot box the content in order to resize it.

Comment: Save the table ro an \sbox. Then rotate and rescale rhe \sbox. Or an lrbox. This should complete the canonicality of the answer.

Comment: In the sense that you can box the contents of a novel (sans chapter breaks) and make it fit, sure, this is always an option. But that is hardly useful! The original table allows page breaks. A reasonable solution needs to allow them, too.